# How to say "I'm finished"?

Tags: translation, grammar

When we've finished doing something like I've finished (doing my homework) what we should say. 
Can we say 好了 "I'm finished"? (Hǎole)

How about "are you finished"?  Can we say "好了吗"?. (Hǎole ma)

Comment: 做完了 in this case, 做好了 sounds weird to me as it is usually used in the situation that you are actually making or building something. If you finished a meal, you could say 吃完了/吃好了, or if you finished doing the dishes, you could say 洗好了.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Usually, there is a **Verb** before the "好了". for example:

   "你作业做好了吗？-- 我**做**好了" translate to English "Have you finished doing homework? -- Yes, I have finished."

   "你电影看完了吗？-- 我**看**完了" translate to English "Have you finished watching movies? -- Yes, I have finished."
2. It is definitly correct to say "好了吗？", when you want to ask "Are you finished?".

Comment: Is it possible to ask like this "你做好了吗?" --我做好了 "Have you finished doing? -- Yes, I have finished."  Can we omit 作业?

Comment: @nkm yes, you can

Answer (score 5):

Depend on the context, 好 and/or 完 can be used.

好 is more oral friendly as there is no emphasize of any difference between the speaker and the listener. In some cases, using 好 may show a closer relation between the parties of conversation than 完.

On the other hand, 完 is more formal. It is a better parallel to "finish" comparing to 好 as the latter has broader usage. Be weary while using 完 as it is often used when the parties involved in conversion are not equal.

For instance, 完 is used when your boss speaks to you, your teacher speaks to you, your group leader speaks to you, etc. 好 on the other hand, tend to be used when your friend speaks to you, your partner speaks to you, etc.

Answer (score 3):

`I'm finished` can be translated to `做好了`， or `做完了`， both make sense for me, nothing  wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You might consider 完 and its associated words for the meaning of "finished."

Comment: I have removed all comments, for extended discussions please use chat. It is preferred if you can provide a complete answer rather than a partial answer when someone is unclear in the first place.